# How to stop Flask rewriting address bar with URL populated by default attributes

Tags: python, flask

Flask in `main.py`:

```
@app.route('/country/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/country', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/country/<value>/<int:page_index>', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/country/<value>/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/country/<value>', methods=['GET'])
def country(value=None, page_index=0):
    return render_template('list.html', title='Countries')
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/company/` the function is called correctly. But the browser address bar is rewritten `http://127.0.0.1:5000/country/None/0`

How can I stop the address bar being updated with the default values for `value` and `page_index`?

Any comments about my decorators welcomed too.

Comment: Nothing in this code is doing that. Do you have a redirect in your function?

Comment: thanks. I've added some detail from my function. would render_template() do this?

Comment: Can you show us the route handler for "company/"?

Comment: the URL rewritten turned out to be a quirky browser/cache issue. Switching to a different browser revealed that the code was working correctly. I've accepted the answer by @Josip Kolarić as I had also solicited advice on the decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting your `value` and `page_index` default values, it will be always be populated. Split the logic for routes in separate routes:

- `/country/` - add route handler without any params - `def country()`
- `/country/<value>` - add route handler with only `value` param - `def country(value)`
- `/country/<value>/<int:page_index>` - add route handler with both `value` and `page_index` param - `def country(value, page_index)`